# How to remove comma and "and" before institutional last author after compiling BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I have the following BibTeX entry:

```
@article{pubmed18800157,
    author = {Heng, T.S. and Painter, M.W. and Immunological Genome Project Consortium},
    title = {The {I}mmunological {G}enome {P}roject: networks of gene expression in immune cells.},
    journal = {Nat. Immunol.},
    pages = {1091-1094},
    volume = {9},
    number ={10},
    year = {2008},
},
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

When the bibliography is generated, it puts comma a the end of the author:
[image]

Notice the comma after `M.W. Painter`. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Thats a duplicate of [Getting Rid of Comma before 'and' in Authors' Names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130180/33933).

Comment: @Christoph Well yes but the answer there doesn't really give much in the way of technical detail!

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, you are right. It wasn't meant to say, that it should be marked as duplicate. I should've said, "look at that question".

Comment: Not part of the question, but as the institutional author is a single 'name', you should put the entire thing in braces.

Comment: Perhaps we should 'reverse dupe' here: this question has answers at the technical level, so might be a better 'main' question.

Comment: the title of your question asks how also to remove the "and".  can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?  perhaps "T.S. Hong and M.W. Painter, Immunological Genome Project Consortium"?  (however, i don't think there's an exiting mechanism for getting *that* output.)

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of that Oxford comma, you'll need to modify the `.bst` file – in your case that is `unsrt.bst`.
Locate the file `.bst` file on your system, copy and rename it (to `unsrtnox.bst`, for example) and put it somewhere LaTeX can find it.

The relevant function is called `FUNCTION {format.names}` (`unsrt.bst`, l. 185).

If you get rid of the four lines

```
numnames #2 >
  { "," * }
  'skip$
if$
```

making it (in our case of `unsrt.bst`)

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
  { namesleft #1 >
      { ", " * t * }
      { t "others" =
          { " et~al." * }
          { " and " * t * }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
    't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

the comma before the last name disappears.

The test above is evoked at the penultimate name (otherwise a comma is printed following the name) and checks if the list contains more than two names, if so, the comma will be printed anyway. Getting rid of this test prevents the comma from being printed.

Answer (score 6):

Complementary to the approach of [editing a `.bst` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131173), if you are willing to shift to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) then you can do this using the [`trad-unsrt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad) style and a very minor customisation:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{pubmed18800157,
    author = {Heng, T. S. and Painter, M. W. and {Immunological Genome Project Consortium}},
    title = {The {Immunological} {Genome} {Project}:
      networks of gene expression in immune cells.},
    journal = {Nat. Immunol.},
    pages = {1091-1094},
    volume = {9},
    number ={10},
    year = {2008},
},
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=trad-unsrt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace \bibstring {and}\space}

\begin{document}

\textcite{pubmed18800157}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with institutional authors: the same is true for any list of three or more authors with the `unsrt` style.

Comment: How can I do this in the `lbx` file? In Hungarian the comma is grammatically wrong, but redefining `\finalnamedelim` in the `lbx` file didn't work for me.

Comment: @marczellm Broadly, I'd say 'you don't'. The reasoning is as follows: the _style_ is defined by the `.bbx` file and is 'language-independent', while the _language strings_ are defined by the `.lbx` file and are of course not. As such, commas are present not because of the _language_ but because of the _style_: bibliography data is not in 'sentence form'.

Comment: For people that are looking for a `biblatex` solution here it might be worth adding that the conceptually more interesting solution is to modify `\finalandcomma` as can be seen in [Biblatex IEEE extra comma before and: author1, author2, and author3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243807/35864) and [Multiple authors in (classicthesis) Bibliography: removing comma before “and”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/35864).