# Changing "and" to "&" and removing Oxford comma in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I need to change the "and" to "&" and remove the Oxford comma in my bibliography. I saw a solution [here for removing the oxford comma](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131162/how-to-remove-comma-and-and-before-institutional-last-author-after-compiling-b) that suggests changing the .bst file, but I'd prefer not to do that if possible. It also suggests using `bibstyle=trad-unsrt` option, but I am not using that `bibstyle`. I could not find any suggestions on how to change the "and" to "&," but it is difficult to search for because of the "&."

EDIT March 31st, 2014 9:02PM EST: I found out how to remove the penultimate comma in the author list when "*et al*" is **not** present (thanks @cfr). However, the issue remains when "*et al*" is present.

EDIT March 31st, 2014 10:21 EST: I found out how to change "and" to "&" and incorporated the code to my MWE.

Here is an image of my citations as is:

Image 1.
[image]

The comma before "*et al*" in the first citation is the one I'd like to remove.

Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
citestyle=numeric,
isbn=false,
bibstyle=authoryear,
maxnames=3, % Max number of names before "et al" starts
minnames=3, % Must show at least three names for citations and bibliography
firstinits=true, % Removes period after first name intial 
terseinits=true, % Removes period after first name intial 
sorting=none] % List citations in order they appear
{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}\addcomma\space} % Bolds volume of citation and adds comma after volume
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} % No prefix for the "pages" field in the bibliography
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} % Removing the comma after last name in bibliography 
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} % Removing the periods after first name intial in bibliography
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace} % Removes period after year in bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}  % Remove quotes from journal title in bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Lists all authors with last name first in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space} % Removes comma after penultimate name

\AtBeginBibliography{% Replaces "and" with "&" in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{}{}%
\addspace\&\space}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{ % Makes the "et al" italicized bibliography
\bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{% Removes "In" from bibliography entries
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list 
{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}} % Adds numbers to references and wraps the text for each bibliography entry
{\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}% 
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}% 
\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}% 
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}% 
\setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}% 
\addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}% 
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}% 
\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}} 
{\endlist} 
{\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.} % Adds a period after each reference number in bibliography

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@article{author2014,
author = {Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B.},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2014}
}
@article{author2013,
author = {Author, A. D. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A.B},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Be excellent, Dudes \supercite{author2013,author2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have solved much of the original problem yourself; you can solve the last bit to remove the Oxford comma before the *et. al.* in the bibliography entries with the following code added to your MWE:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{ % Removes comma before the "et al"
{\finalandcomma}%
}{%
\addspace%
}{}{}
```

This gives:

[image: bibliography]

The final working example becomes:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
citestyle=numeric,
isbn=false,
bibstyle=authoryear,
maxnames=3, % Max number of names before "et al" starts
minnames=3, % Must show at least three names for citations and bibliography
firstinits=true, % Removes period after first name intial 
terseinits=true, % Removes period after first name intial 
sorting=none] % List citations in order they appear
{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}\addcomma\space} % Bolds volume of citation and adds comma after volume
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} % No prefix for the "pages" field in the bibliography
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} % Removing the comma after last name in bibliography 
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{} % Removing the periods after first name intial in bibliography
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace} % Removes period after year in bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}  % Remove quotes from journal title in bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Lists all authors with last name first in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space} % Removes comma after penultimate name

\AtBeginBibliography{% Replaces "and" with "&" in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{}{}%
\addspace\&\space}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{ % Removes comma before the "et al"
{\finalandcomma}%
}{%
\addspace%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{ % Makes the "et al" italicized bibliography
\bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{% Removes "In" from bibliography entries
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list 
{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}} % Adds numbers to references and wraps the text for each bibliography entry
{\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}% 
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}% 
\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}% 
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}% 
\setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}% 
\addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}% 
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}% 
\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}} 
{\endlist} 
{\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.} % Adds a period after each reference number in bibliography

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@article{author2014,
author = {Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B.},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2014}
}
@article{author2013,
author = {Author, A. D. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A.B},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Be excellent, Dudes \supercite{author2013,author2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I did try playing with the \xpatchmacro but I just couldn't get it to work. I am still new to Latex but I am learning a lot from this site and its contributors.

Comment: This is nice, but it does not get rid of the oxford comma from the citations. How does one do that?

Comment: The standard way to get rid of Oxford commas is `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}` as in my answer below and in [Multiple authors in (classicthesis) Bibliography: removing comma before “and”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/35864)

Answer (score 11):

If it makes sense I'd suggest using a language that does not have the Oxford comma (`british` for example).

But if that is not an option, a simple `\let\finalandcomma=\empty` in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}` should do it:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}
```

If we use that, we do not even need `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}`.

I have also changed the redefinition of `\finalnamedelim` to `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}`, as the test added nothing.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=numeric,
isbn=false,
bibstyle=authoryear,
maxnames=3,
minnames=3,
giveninits=true,
terseinits=true,
sorting=none]
{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareDelimFomat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}
  {\bibstring{andothers}}
  {\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
    {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}%
     \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod} % Adds a period after each reference number in bibliography

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2014,
author = {Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B.},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2014}
}
@article{author2013,
author = {Author, A. D. and Author, A. B. and Author, A. B. and Author, A.B},
journal = {Journal of the happy but frustrated biblatex user},
pages = {1070--1074},
title = {{Biblatex hurts so good}},
volume = {10},
date = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  Be excellent, Dudes \supercite{author2013,author2014}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: A question has been asked regarding this post by a user who could not comment here directly. The question from @geras can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489442/how-do-i-specify-what-language-i-want-to-use?noredirect=1#comment1236087_489442).