# How to get rid of the "Oxford comma" in a listing of three or more authors?

Tags: biblatex

The following bib entry hat three authors but the last one is separated with `, and` instead of just `and`. Is it possible to remove that comma?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A and Schur, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is known as the Oxford comma. If you write this for yourself you can omit it, but if this is a paper or thesis or something like that you should talk with your advisor whether to omit it or not.

Comment: offtopic: you miss `.` after `S` and `A`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168591/35864

Comment: The fact that such a grammar mistake has ended up in Biblatex is quite interesting.

Comment: As far as I have understood it is not a grammar mistake at all. Both variants should be correct, should't they?

Comment: @ValerieD. Certainly. There is no grammatical error here. Optional punctuation within a phrase can't cause grammatical errors. But I see no Oxford comma here, only two 'and's where there should be one.

Comment: @EJP There is a confusion here, because the given code is not not BibTeX output, but the input. BibTeX splits the names at the "ands" and applies its own rules (under the given circumstances "S. Baur, A. Schmid, and B. Schur")

Comment: @EJP And indeed `author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A and Schur, B.},` with *two* `and`s is the only correct way to give a list of three names. The output will usually not contain several 'and's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove it change the definition of `\finalnamedelim`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Baur, S. and Schmid, A. and Schur, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why `S.\ ` produces error?

Comment: @Sigur because some parsing of `biblatex` doesn't work with it :) Why use it?

Comment: I prefer the solution where one redefines `\finalandcomma` direcrtly. If you want to redefine `\finalnamedelim` I strongly recommend to retain `\bibstring{and}` instead of a hard-coded `and` and also to use `\addspace` for the first `\space`. Since `finalnamedelim` is now a context-sensitive delimiter I would also use `\DeclareDelimFormat` instead of `\renewcommand`: `\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}`

Comment: @Skillmon, to change spacing after it, since it is not end of sentence punctuation.

Comment: @Sigur it doesn't change anything, but `{.\ }` works.

Comment: @Sigur You don't need to tell TeX that the dot in `S.` is not a sentence-ending full stop. `biblatex` handles the punctuation and knows about this. It has never been necessary to mark up the `.` in `.bib` files specially and `biblatex` is no exception. In fact as you saw, messing about with the punctuation can even do harm. Names are always given as `First Last`, `F. Last`, `Last, First` or `Last, F.` nothing more is required (no `~`, no `.\ `, no `\@.`)

Comment: @Sigur In fact the dot after a capital letter will normally be considered an abbreviation dot anyway and the `.\ ` is not needed at all. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2230/35864 This holds for all of LaTeX and is not specific to `biblatex`.

Comment: @Skillmon If you want to incorporate the suggestion from my first comment into your answer that would be appreciated. I still feel that my solution to get rid of the Oxford comma is the conceptually nicer one, but I would upvote your answer if it did not completely destroy the localisation (by using `and` instead of `\bibstring{and}`) and inhibit the punctuation tracker (by using `\space` for the first space instead of `\addspace`) and the context-sensitive punctuation interface (by using `\renewcommand` instead of `\DeclareDelimFormat`).

Comment: @moewe I did not update because your answer is in every aspect better than mine. That's why I upvoted it. Don't know why I did get so many upvotes, honestly.

Comment: Well, it works, is short, the OP accepted it, that's quite some reasons to upvote.

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
}
```

to get rid of Oxford commas (and semicolons) in general. Since the definitions live in the `.lbx` files you can't simply change them in your preamble, you need a language-specific `\DefineBibliographyExtras`. Many other languages including `british` don't use the Oxford comma by default, so you could consider switching if you don't write in American English.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]