# Use biblatex's \finalandcomma in text

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

How do I use biblatex's serial comma (`\finalandcomma`) outside of the bibliography? The following minimal example results in an error `Undefined control sequence. [  One, two\finalandcomma]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
  One, two\finalandcomma{} and three.
\end{document}
```

But if I [disable Oxford/serial commas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415943/71332), then it works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{% Remove Oxford/serial commas
  \let\finalandcomma\empty
}
\begin{document}
  One, two\finalandcomma{} and three.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message from your first MWE is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\finalandcomma ->\addcomma 
                           
l.5   One, two\finalandcomma
                            {} and three.
?
```

That means that it isn't `\finalandcomma` that is undefined. `\finalandcomma` is defined as `\addcomma`. And `\addcomma` is the command that is undefined here.

Indeed the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains in §4.7 *Punctuation and Spacing* that

> Note that these facilities [`\addcomma` and friends] are only made available locally in citations and bibliographies. They will not affect any other part of a document.

That has two reasons: For one these commands can only work properly in a certain space factor setup that is generally not used outside of citations. Secondly, `biblatex` keeps these macros in a private name space to avoid name clashes.

The example with the disabled `\finalandcomma` works because then the macro expands to an empty replacement text, which obviously cannot end up undefined.

All in all I would recommend you define your own macro with a different name and do not rely on `biblatex`'s `\finalandcomma`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\newcommand*{\listfinalcomma}{}

\begin{document}
  One, two\listfinalcomma{} and three.
\end{document}
```

If you really want to use `biblatex`'s `\finalandcomma` another way to work around this problem is to define `\addcomma`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\addcomma}{,}

\begin{document}
  One, two\finalandcomma{} and three.
\end{document}
```

`biblatex`'s own definition of `\addcomma` will still be used when `biblatex` is in charge, but outside of `biblatex`'s realms we have a fallback definition that should be good enough.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you! I will do as you suggest and define my own command :-)