# Each Entry need new line

Tags: biblatex

I have using `biblatex` package and like to print each entry newline instead of **; with space**.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel,hyperref,fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes,microtype}
\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipab730bbib32,
  author={Doherty J P and Moore M A and Kim J M and Bray A J},
  year={1994},
  journaltitle={Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume={72},
}
@article{ipab730bbib32a,
  author={Kardar M and Zee A},
  year={1996},
  journaltitle={Nucl. Phys. B},
  volume={464},
}
@article{ipab730bbib32b,
  author={Bork L V and Ogarkov S L},
  year={2014},
  journaltitle={Theor. Math. Phys.},
  volume={178},
}
@set{staticsets,
  entryset  = {ipab730bbib32,ipab730bbib32a,ipab730bbib32b},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

After (1994); need enter mark and after (1996); need enter mark. It means each entry should be new line. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that controls the punctuation between set entries is called `\entrysetpunct`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, maxbibnames=5, giveninits]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimi}{\addnbspace}

\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\addsemicolon\par}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ipab730bbib32,
  author       = {Doherty, J. P. and Moore, M. A. and Kim, J. M. and Bray, A. J.},
  year         = {1994},
  journaltitle = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume       = {72},
}
@article{ipab730bbib32a,
  author       = {Kardar, M. and Zee, A.},
  year         = {1996},
  journaltitle = {Nucl. Phys. B},
  volume       = {464},
}
@article{ipab730bbib32b,
  author       = {Bork, L. V. and Ogarkov, S. L.},
  year         = {2014},
  journaltitle = {Theor. Math. Phys.},
  volume       = {178},
}
@set{staticsets,
  entryset  = {ipab730bbib32,ipab730bbib32a,ipab730bbib32b},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three set entries. Separated by line breaks.]

Comment: How to remove comma before `and`. like `Kim J M, and` should be `Kim J M and` only.

Comment: @Balaji https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415943/35864