# How do I specify what language I want to use?

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation, languages

In this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168625/160474

the author says
"I would suggest using a language that does not have the Oxford comma (`british` for example).".

What does he mean by that? In particular is it about the language of the whole document or just the bibliography?

It seems to me that it would be a good thing for me to do at least because I want to write in British and I don't want Oxford commas in my bibliography. I use Bibtex.

Comment: It may be a good idea to ask the author of the post this question directly in the comments of the original post.

Comment: Yes, but I need 15 reputation points to do this.

Comment: I added a comment in the original post for for and tagged you in it. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use BibTeX the linked answer is going to be pretty much useless to you since it only applies to `biblatex`. If you want help with your concrete problem, I suggest you show us a short example document that reproduces the output you get at the moment (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: To explain the linked answer a bit more: Usually (and in the linked question) typesets the bibliography in the active (normally main) document language. In this case it was `english` and the `english` localisation for `biblatex` activates the Oxford comma. Other localisations such as `british` (or `french`, `dutch`, ...) don't use the Oxford comma. So the first option would be to check if it makes sense to switch the language to a language without Oxford comma. In that case that should mean switching the document language. That is situational though, so I reworded the passage a bit.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/35864 explains this slightly better.

Comment: Thanks @jGaboardi and @moewe , so I need to use `babel` to specify the language as `british`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can specify the language as `british` (or `UKenglish` as I chose because I think it sounds more pro--I think it's exactly the same thing) by using the `babel` package but I need to use `biblatex`, not just `bibtex`, for it to apply to the bibliography too.

I did it like in the first out of the solutions proposed by @moewe here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285649/160474
although I used `bibtex` instead of `biber` as backend because I had some problems with switching to the latter.