# Removing Oxford Comma before "et al." in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm trying to remove commas in my bibliography before "et al." Such as in the example:

Andreas A.,et al. (2008)...

I would like to simply be:

Andreas A. et al. (2008)

I've reviewed other questions/answers related to this topic, but haven't been able to successfully implement them.  I'm using a template that uses natbib.  I was originally explicitly specifying a bib style, but when I commented that line, nothing changed.

Comment: Can you provide us with a complete document that replicates your current setup? This should be in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: I suppose a solution is in the answers to a [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168591/changing-and-to-and-removing-oxford-comma-in-bibliography).

Comment: @Bernard No, your linked question uses `biblatex` and Tom is using `natbib` so that solution won't work. Here is a more relevant duplicate: [How to remove comma and "and" before institutional last author after compiling BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131162)

Comment: @Alan Munn: I hadn't noticed. However, biblatex has a compatibility mode, so may be he can use biblatex?  I know very little about natbib and have no idea if punctuation is easy to customise.

Comment: @Bernard The compatibility mode in `biblatex` is only there to allow you to use `natbib` citation commands. It doesn't allow you to use existing `.bst` files.