# \bibliographystyle{alpha} and an extra comma with multiple authors

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the following code:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}
```

And this is the first entry in my .bib file

```
@ARTICLE{Sos, 
AUTHOR="Bíró, A. and 
        Deshouillers, J.~M. and 
        Sós, V.~T.",
TITLE="Good approximation..."
}
```

I expect to obtain this

```
[BDS01] A. Bíró, J. M. Deshouillers, V. T. Sós. Good approximation...
```

But I get this

```
[BDS01] A. Bíró, J. M. Deshouillers, and V. T. Sós. Good approximation...
```

Why there is an extra and?

This may helps understanding my .bib file:
[How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/how-to-properly-write-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file)

Comment: Since your question is evidently not about `biblatex`, but about a classical BibTeX style, I have removed the tag. The output you see is just the way `alpha.bst` formats authors, i.e. it adds an "and" before the last author. If you don't want that you can either look for another style that does what you want or modify the `.bst` file yourself.

Comment: Looking better around I can tell you that you are right: it adds automatically "and".
But usually it adds only "and" not ", and". Why there is the extra comma? (I'have better modifying title of the question!)

Comment: That is the so-called Oxford comma, apparently it is not unusual to add a comma before an and in American English. There must have been something about that on this site before.

Comment: Maybe [How to remove comma and “and” before institutional last author after compiling BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131162/35864) can help you.

Comment: There is no need to remove the question. If the question I linked to helped you, we can close it as a duplicate. If not, make your question more specific by including an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and explaining in more detail what you expect and I'm sure people will be happy to give you a hand.

Comment: Yes we can close as duplicate!