# Biblatex IEEE extra comma before and: author1, author2, and author3

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, punctuation, ieee-style

When I use Biblatex with style=ieee, I get a COMMA and a AND before the third author in my bibliography:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe2015,
author={Doe1, J. and Doe2 K. and Doe3 L.},
title={Why I get this extra comma before the 'and' ?}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Citation here: \cite{doe2015}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Where is this listed as IEEE style?

My question is: how to fix (remove) the last comma before the "and"?

Also, I think this is not following IEEE anyway:

This: http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf

is mentioning:

> three or more authors: J. K. Author et al.

Why is this not implemented? Where can I find the "official" IEEE citation guidelines which is implemented by Biblatex/IEEE?

How can I enable this mode to list only the first author?

Comment: For the comma, this is recommended by basic English grammar: http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/020204whencommabfand.htm As for the number of authors "J. K. Author et al.", I think it should be avoided as it somehow lacks respect for the remaining authors. In electronic documents, having a long list of authors is fine.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130180/getting-rid-of-comma-before-and-in-authors-names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is enough to modify the value of `\finalandcomma`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe2015,
author={Doe1, J. and Doe2 K. and Doe3 L.},
title={Why I get this extra comma before the 'and'?},
year = 2015
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand\finalandcomma{}}

\begin{document}

Citation here: \cite{doe2015}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As mentioned by @moewe, a nicer way, instead of `\AtBeginBibliography{…}` is to write `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Also thanks on behalf of future vistors with this question.

Comment: I believe a slightly nicer way is `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}`. You will see a difference to the simple `\AtBeginBibliography` when using a style like `authoryear` and works with three authors: `\cite{companion}`. Cf. [Multiple authors in (classicthesis) Bibliography: removing comma before “and”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/35864)

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for the link. I've added your way to my answer. I agree with you it's nicer.

Comment: Indeed, you will not only find that it is nicer, but also that only that approach gives satisfying results in all situations, `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand\finalandcomma{}}` does not get rid of the Oxford commas in citations and probably has trouble if the language is switched in the bibliography. You can try the following example ...

Comment: ... `\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe2015,
author={Doe1, J. and Doe2 K. and Doe3 L.},
title={Why},
year = 2015
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand\finalandcomma{}}
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}

\begin{document}
Citation here: \cite{doe2015,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document} `

Answer (score 7):

The implementation in `biblatex-ieee` follows as far as possible that in [`ieeetran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran). The latter describes itself as being official correct, so this is a reasonable reference point.

On the specific point about the 'Oxford comma' here, if you look at `texdoc ieeetran` and for example ref. 20 you will see

```
C. Barratt, M. C. Grant, and D. Carlisle.
```

with a comma. This is the reason that this is implemented as part of `biblatex-ieee`.

If you wish to override the behaviour, adding

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  maxnames = 2,
  minnames = 1,
}
```

after loading `biblatex` will truncate the author list.

Comment: Jospeh, thanks for your explanation but I still want to get rid of this oxford comma in Biblatex/IEEE. Is there a simple way (eg switch) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You've written the authors' names incorrectly and Bibtex is confused.

If you put the surname first followed by the initial you have to put a comma behind each surname:
author={Doe1, J. and Doe2, K. and Doe3, L.},

Alternatively you could put initials first and then surnames, in which case no commas are needed:
author={J. Doe1 and K. Doe2 and L. Doe3},