# Multiple authors in (classicthesis) Bibliography: removing comma before "and"

Tags: biblatex

Working on Classicthesis (version 4.2), I'm finding that by default the bibliography prints a comma before "and", resulting as below.

> [22] Andrew McAfee, Erik Brynjolfsson, Thomas H Davenport, DJ Patil, and Dominic Barton. “Big data.” In: The management revo- lution. Harvard Bus Rev 90.10 (2012), pp. 61–67.

With classicthesis template as MWE (`numeric-comp` for package `biblatex`), how could this be fixed?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168591/changing-and-to-and-removing-oxford-comma-in-bibliography), which explain how to remove a comma after "et. al" in a similar situation, didn't help.

However, reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131162/how-to-remove-comma-and-and-before-institutional-last-author-after-compiling-b), I've come to the conclusion that classicthesis uses something called Natbib and that I'd need to locate a .bst file and edit accordingly. However, I cannot locate such a file in my directory... ?

Comment: You can relatively easily do that with `biblatex`

Comment: First, and most important of all: which version of the classic thesis template are you using? They switched to biblatex in the latest one!  In any case, this has nothing to do with classicthesis. It only depends on the bibliography style you're using.

Comment: I'm using "A Classic Thesis Style v4.2" - so the latest version, and thus biblatex. What are the implications of this regarding my next step to solve this... ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `biblatex`, there are two ways to get rid of the Oxford comma.

#### Use a different localisation

You can use a localisation that drops the Oxford comma.
The `american` (and thus also the `english` locale – technically it is the other way round, but never mind) have `\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}`, so they print a comma before "and" if there are three or more items in a list.
The locales `british` and `australian` drop the Oxford comma.

So you could request `british` English from `babel` and not just `english`, *keep in mind though that this will have other effects as well*. So this is only an option if you should (or at least could) already be using a different localisation.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,companion,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Redefine `\finalandcomma` and `\finalandsemicolon`

If you want to keep on using the same localisations and just remove the Oxford comma, go with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma=\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon=\empty
}
```

where `\finalandcomma` is the Oxford comma and `\finalandsemicolon` is the equivalent for semicolons instead of commas.
It is necessary to put this into `\DefineBibliographyExtras`, because as we have seen `\finalandcomma` and `\finalandsemicolon` are language-specific commands.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma=\empty
  \let\finalandsemicolon=\empty
}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin,companion,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: For those interested: in [bug report #127 *Setting \finalandcomma in preamble doesn't work* at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/bugs/127/) Philipp Lehman that `\finalandcomma` is handled on a per-language basis which is why we need `\DefineBibliographyExtras` and friends here.

Comment: I knew a retag would bring you here :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Sometimes it doesn't take a lot `;-)`. I should probably read non-filtered lists of questions more often.

Comment: @Mico Merci....