# How to remove the final comma in a list of authors; biblatex with natbib compatibility mode

Tags: biblatex, natbib

the MWE will show you the problem I am faced with. I want to remove the comma after the second author so that I obtain: "author1, author2 and author3 (year)". With the settings in the MWE, I obtain: "author1, author2, and author3 (year)".

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    headsepline,
    dottedtoc,
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, 
    ngerman,american,
    ]{scrreprt} 


   \PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
   \usepackage{inputenc}
   \usepackage[american]{babel}

   \PassOptionsToPackage{%
    backend=biber,
    isbn = false,
    doi = false,
    language=auto,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=1,
    natbib=true
    }{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{citation-292640248.bib}

    \usepackage{classicthesis} 

    \begin{document}
        When citing with citet one obtains for example: 
        \citet{Antoniadis.1992}.
    \end{document}
```

The corresponding bib.-file reads:

```
@article{Antoniadis.1992,
 author = {Antoniadis, D. and Mantzavinos, D. and Stamatoudis, M.},
 year = {1992},
 month = {03},
 pages = {161-165},
 title = {Effect of chamber volume an diameter on bubble formation at plate 
 orifices},
 volume = {70}
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either your typographic objective (removing the so-called Oxford comma) or parts of your document setup need to adjust.

Since you've (a) chosen `american` to be the primary language for `babel` and (b) set the option `language=auto` for `biblatex`, you're getting the Oxford comma before the final "and" precisely *because* using the Oxford comma is, in fact, standard US-English (as well as Canadian-English) formatting practice.

You have (at least) three options:

- Do nothing, i.e., keep your current document setup and get used to the Oxford comma.
- Switch to a variant of English (e.g., `british` or `australian`, among others) that doesn't employ the Oxford comma by default. Note that such a switch can have far-reaching and unexpected consequences, in part because hyphenation patterns tend to differ considerably across variants of the English language. (Aside: Isn't it mildly amusing that the Oxford comma is used in the U.S. but not in the U.K.?!)
- If you do need to use the `american` variant of English as the default language but simply can't stand the look of Oxford commas, insert the instruction

  ```
  \DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}
  ```

  after loading `biblatex`.

For much more information on this topic, see the posting [Multiple authors in (classicthesis) Bibliography: removing comma before "and"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283078/5001).

Comment: Thanks, this worked out well. Since I'm not a native I've never heard before about Oxford comma. I have a second problem with my bibliography. The command \Citet{} for defining capital letters in the citations does not work. This is a problem for me because I have a lot of authors like "van Krevelen" or "de Nevers". \Citet{} should do this properly which is also noted in the biblatex documentation but somehow \citet{} and \Citet{} gives the same output.

Comment: @beeem - If `biblatex` is loaded with the option `natbib`, most of (but not all) commands of the `natbib` package are *emulated* by `biblatex`; it is not the case that the full `natbib`  package itself is loaded. Since this is a rather different topic from the one in the posting shown above, please post a *new query* to ask how to to get `\Citet` -- or a close relative -- to work under `biblatex`.